# Hiding a part of a website based on a tickbox

Tags: c#

I am basically trying to write a piece of c# that works with a current project I am working on, the idea behind it is that it will be a tickbox that may be ticked and when it is ticked it will write to a database that a certain image on the page should be written (doesn't have to use the writing to db part if theres a better way to do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is ASP.Net, you could use a `Panel` and hide the image when the checkbox isn't checked:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel" runat="server" Visible="false">
     <img src="" alt="MY IMAGE" />
</panel>
```

And in the code behind:

```
panel.Visible = tickbox.Checked;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store information just with one tick on tickbox then you have to include tickbox event as

```
If tickbox.box_name=enable
{
  Enter here SQL coding for data insert
}
```

This is basic concept which will definitely helps you.